# Check nonce in the new bulk_edit_posts action

Tags: nonce, bulk

In a plugin I'm developing, I need to add the ability to bulk edit some meta fields in a custom post named "lot". I want to use the new `bulk_edit_posts` hook added in WP 6.3. This is the code I came up with:

```
function my_show_bulk_edit_lot_metabox( $column_name ) {
    static $print_nonce = true;
    if ( $print_nonce ) {
        $print_nonce = false;
        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'lot_edit_nonce' );
    }

    switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'price':
            ?>
        <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right inline-edit-lot">
            <div class="inline-edit-col column-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                <label class="inline-edit-group">
                    <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Price' ); ?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="price" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
            <?php
            break;
        case 'auction':
            $auctions = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type'        => 'auction',
                    'post_status'      => 'any',
                    'numberposts'      => -1,
                    'suppress_filters' => 0,
                )
            );
            ?>
        <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right inline-edit-lot">
            <div class="inline-edit-col column-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                <label class="inline-edit-group">
                    <span class="title"><?php _e( 'Auction' ); ?></span>
                    <select name="auction_id" id="auction_id">
                        <option value="0"><?php _e( '&mdash; No Change &mdash;' ); ?></option>
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $auctions as $auction ) {
                            $title = $auction->post_title;
                            if ( empty( $title ) ) {
                                $title = __( '(no title)' );
                            }
                            $title = esc_html( $title );
                            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $auction->ID ) . '">' . $title . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
            <?php
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'bulk_edit_custom_box', 'my_show_bulk_edit_lot_metabox', 10, 2 );

function my_save_bulk_edit_lot( $updated, $shared_post_data ) {
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( wp_unslash( $shared_post_data['lot_edit_nonce'] ), plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) && 'lot' === $shared_post_data['post_type'] ) {
        foreach ( $updated as $post_id ) {
            if ( ! empty( $shared_post_data['auction_id'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'auction_id', wp_unslash( $shared_post_data['auction_id'] ) );
            }
            if ( ! empty( $shared_post_data['price'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'price', wp_unslash( $shared_post_data['price'] ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'bulk_edit_posts', 'my_save_bulk_edit_lot', 10, 2 );
```

Everything is working as expected if I remove the nonce check. This is the content of the `$shared_post_data` var inside the `my_save_bulk_edit_lot()` function:

```
Array
(
    [s] => 
    [post_type] => lot
    [_wpnonce] => ea9131e013
    [_wp_http_referer] => /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=lot
    [action] => edit
    [m] => 0
    [filter_by_auction] => 
    [paged] => 1
    [auction_id] => 0
    [price] => 100€
    [autodescription-bulk] => Array
        (
            [noindex] => nochange
            [nofollow] => nochange
            [noarchive] => nochange
        )

    [bulk_edit] => Update
    [post_view] => list
    [screen] => edit-lot
    [post] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7176
            [1] => 7174
        )

    [action2] => edit
)
```

As you can see there's no trace of the `lot_edit_nonce` nonce value I print in the `my_show_bulk_edit_lot_metabox()` function. There's a `_wpnonce` value, though. Do I need to check for this nonce instead? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the nonce verification to work, I needed to replace this:

```
wp_verify_nonce( wp_unslash( $shared_post_data['lot_edit_nonce'] ), plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) )
```

with this:

```
wp_verify_nonce( wp_unslash( $shared_post_data['_wpnonce'] ), 'bulk-posts' )
```